# Pivot Room SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, pivot

Boa noite, pessoal.

Estou usando o select abaixo, mas gostaria que os turnos virassem colunas. Como não tem a opção do pivot, como posso fazer isso?

```
select tma.turma as TURMAS, tno.turno as TURNOS, count (tno.turno) as QTDE
from (select * from Visita v 
where 
(v.dataCadastro BETWEEN (strftime(v.dataCadastro, '2021-04-01')) AND 
(strftime(v.dataCadastro, '2021-05-31')))) resultado
INNER JOIN Turma tma ON (resultado.turma_id = tma.id) 
INNER JOIN Turno tno ON (resultado.turno_id = tno.id) 
group by TURMAS, TURNOS
```

[image]

Por exemplo:

[image]

Vi algumas soluções com CASE, mas pode haver outros cadastros de "turmas" e "turnos" posteriormente, então não me ajudaria.

Answer (score 0):

nem sempre o pivot vai ser uma opção viavel, mas existem alternativas pra ele

voce poderia tentar usar o CASE WHEN

com PIVOT

```
SELECT U.ANO, U.BANCO, U.INVESTIMENTOS, U.OUTROS
FROM @CONTAS AS C
PIVOT (
    SUM(C.VALOR) FOR
    C.TIPO IN (INVESTIMENTOS, OUTROS)  
) AS U
```

com CASE WHEN da pra fazer o mesmo

```
SELECT C.ANO, C.BANCO, 
    INVESTIMENTOS = SUM(CASE WHEN C.TIPO = 'INVESTIMENTOS' THEN C.VALOR END),
    OUTROS = SUM(CASE WHEN C.TIPO = 'OUTROS' THEN C.VALOR END)
FROM @CONTAS AS C
GROUP BY C.ANO, C.BANCO
```

boa sorte!

Comment: Infelizmente, o CASE não me ajudará, pois os valores da tabela não são fixos. O usuário poderá cadastrar qualquer coisa e quantos itens quiser. Assim, não conseguirei usar o CASE.